# t-Boc protection of amide (urea)

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, protecting-groups

I'm trying to prepare protected urea and I'd like to protect it with some alkali stable PG. Is it possible to protect urea with t-Boc? Or is there another way to get boc-protected urea?
[image]

Comment: Its commercially available. Google "boc urea".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'd like to prepare my own. We are not allowed to order from China (University rules) and I have all starting materials that I possibly need.

Comment: Reflux with BOC2O and DMAP in MeCN

Comment: Check this:Tetrahedron Lett. 2014, 55(4), 842–844 (but method is for mono-protected).

Comment: Thank you both for answers Waylander and Mathew, I will try to run this reaction tomorrow.